# Sweave only produces NAs when using Umlauts.

Tags: r, sweave

I have a problem with Sweave. As soon as I use any mutated vowels/Umlauts (ü, ä, etc.) Sweave produces an NA in the document although it worked before. I don't know what to do, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is an example of a Test.Rnw file:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
%aä
\begin{document}
The following section gives some descriptive statistics. ä
\end{document}
```

Although the file is produced, it only includes two NAs.

Also, I get the following warning message:

```
Warning message:
running command '"C:\PROGRA~2\MIKTEX~1.9\miktex\bin\texi2dvi.exe" --quiet --pdf     "First_Paper_Test.tex"  -I "C:/Program Files/R/R-2.13.1/share/texmf/tex/latex" -I   "C:/Program Files/R/R-2.13.1/share/texmf/bibtex/bst"' had status 1
```

If I delete the Umlauts, I do not have a problem at all. Also, if I add further paragraphs without umlauts, those paragraphs show up just fine. My sessionInfo():

```
R version 2.13.1 (2011-07-08)
Platform: x86_64-pc-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] C

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tools_2.13.1
```

I'm running Windows 7.

Comment: I agree with @richiemorrisroe. That being said, what is the encoding of the file you're trying to `Sweave`? I keep all my files in utf-8.

Comment: I thought of posting it here and not on a TeX related site because I don't think it is a TeX related problem.  When I open the .tex file created by Sweave and change the NAs with the Umlauts, it compiles just fine. At least if I change [utf8] to [latin1] (I found that hint somewhere else). However, I still have the problem that Sweave replaces the Umlauts with NAs.

Comment: Related question here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7509395, http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/28710

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your R is running in a C locale, not a UTF-8 locale. As R has to parse and update the file, I'm not surprised it doesn't know what to do with those characters. Try running Sweave/R in a UTF-8 locale and see if that helps.

For example, Sweave-ing your file from within R produces:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%aä
\usepackage{Sweave}
\begin{document}
The following section gives some descriptive statistics. ä
\end{document}
```

where my R is running in:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 2.13.1 Patched (2011-07-08 r56332)
Platform: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu (64-bit)

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_GB.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
 [3] LC_TIME=en_GB.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_GB.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=C              LC_MESSAGES=en_GB.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_GB.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_GB.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
 [1] tools     grid      splines   stats     graphics  grDevices utils    
 [8] datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] pscl_1.03.10     vcd_1.2-9        colorspace_1.0-1 gam_1.04        
[5] coda_0.14-2      lattice_0.19-23  mvtnorm_0.9-96   MASS_7.3-13
```

To see the current locale use `Sys.getlocale()` and to set a new locale use `Sys.setlocale()`. Also, see section 3 of the [R for Windows FAQ](http://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/rw-FAQ.html#Languages-and-Internationalization) and links to other areas of the FAQ therein. There is also a small amount of info in the [R Installation & Administration Manual](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-admin.html#Locales-under-Windows).

Comment: Great advice.  But how does one do this?  How do I change the locale?

Comment: @Andrie OP is on Windows, which I'm not familiar with. `Sys.setlocale()` seems relevant and the R for Windows FAQ. I didn't add this info at the time because I am not familiar with the OS in question but your comment prompted me to take a peak...

Comment: @Gavin Simpson Thanks a lot, I guess that could be the answer. Unfortunately, I can't change my locale because of the issue mentioned here: [Sys.setlocale() issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5345132/sys-setlocale-request-to-set-locale-cannot-be-honored) That was the reason I went for Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL", "C") in the first place. And since I am using English formatted dates in my analysis, I can't use my standard locale (which is the German one, I guess). As I mentioned, my Sweave file used to work, which lets me believe that the problem only occurred after I updated to R2.13.1.

Comment: Thanks to the hints of @Gavin Simpson, @Roman Luštrik and @richiemorrisroe I came to the conclusion that this workaround might be the easiest solution: I manually add the Umlauts with \"a, \"u, etc in the Sweave file. Then the file compiles just fine. Thanks for your help!