# Sweave generating invalid LaTeX

Tags: hyperref, sweave, r

I've encountered a problem when I'm using Sweave to convert an .Rnw file into a .tex file. Sweave is replacing three options from hyperref's `\hypersetup` block with the value `NA`.

This is the section in the .Rnw file

```
\hypersetup{
baseurl={.},
%bookmarks=true,         % show bookmarks bar?
unicode=false,          % non-Latin characters in Acrobat’s bookmarks
pdftoolbar=true,        % show Acrobat’s toolbar?
pdfmenubar=true,        % show Acrobat’s menu?
pdffitwindow=false,     % window fit to page when opened
pdfstartview={FitH},    % fits the width of the page to the window
```

The resulting LaTeX for the same section comes out as:

```
\hypersetup{
baseurl={.},
%bookmarks=true,         % show bookmarks bar?
NA
NA
NA
pdffitwindow=false,     % window fit to page when opened
pdfstartview={FitH},    % fits the width of the page to the window
```

As far as I can tell the rest of the document is fine. Removing the offending sections allows the compilation of the LaTeX. I'm running R 2.13.1. Has anyone else encountered this problem? Alternatively, could anyone suggest what Sweave finds objectionable about those three options in particular?

Comment: Related question here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/23273

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that you have cut and pasted the `\hypersetup` commands from a PDF, and there are invalid characters in the code, specifically the right single quotation mark `’` If you replace those characters with regular single quote marks `'`, the file should compile.  This is caused by the way `Sweave` handles its input, not by the TeX file itself.

So the reason that it is those three lines is that they all contain the string "Acrobat’s".

**Update**

After some troubleshooting it seems that the underlying problem is a mismatch between the actual file encoding and the locale that R assumes when it runs `Sweave` on the file. In my particular case (running `Sweave` from within TeXShop) the locale wasn't being set properly. The solution was to add

```
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

to the script within TeXShop that was running `Sweave`.  Depending on how you are running `Sweave` the problem may be the same: you need to make sure that the encoding of the file matches the encoding that R is using when `Sweave` processes the file. If you are running from within an editor, check the script that it uses to compile `Sweave` documents; if you are running from the command line, check that your `.bashrc` or `.profile` has the locale set correctly.

For a minimal test document to show this, see this stackoverflow question: [Sweave doesn't seem to get .Rnw file encoding right](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7509395/958220).

Thanks a lot to [Aaron](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/2823/aaron) for helping to troubleshoot this problem with me.

Comment: See the `iconv` function for details.  Sweave calls this function on each line, converting from the original file encoding to the current locale encoding.  `iconv` can substitute a character string when it gets to something it can't reencode, but Sweave doesn't use this feature so it instead returns NA. So another solution might be to change your current locale to one that understands the right quote.  However, you'd want to make sure LaTeX could handle the result properly, which could be difficult.

Comment: @Aaron I thought about that, but it doesn't seem to help.  On my Mac, `sessionInfo()` returns `en_US.UTF-8`, yet with the `.Rnw` file saved as UTF8  the document still produces NAs.

Comment: @AlanMunn thanks, the `'`s were causing the problem. The weird thing is that I'd not touched that preamble in months and the previous versions of Sweave (or more accurately pgfSweave) had not exhibited this problem.

Comment: @AlanMunn abd @Alastair, Perhaps it's an OS or version issue then; on my Mac I have the same encoding according to `sessionInfo()`, but I don't get NAs.

Comment: @Aaron I wonder if the problem is the locale from within the `R.app` (which is correct) vs. the locale when R is called from the command line.

Comment: Maybe, though on my system, both give UTF8.

Comment: @Aaron Checking mine, the two are also the same, so you're right. I woudn't mind to get to the bottom of this. Is there an appropriate R forum/list that might have some answers?

Comment: stackoverflow has a robust R community; I'd start there.  I'll let you ask since I'm not getting the NAs, though I'm curious too!

Comment: @Aaron Ok. Here's the stackoverflow question: [Sweave doesn't seem to get .Rnw file encoding right](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7509395/958220). Let's see what happens.

Comment: @Alan, nice update to your answer, and you're welcome!