# \SweaveInput{...} with UTF-8 encoding?

Tags: unicode, sweave, input-encodings

Some hack [here](http://tolstoy.newcastle.edu.au/R/e10/help/10/05/4889.html).

In ?RweaveLatex manual, I found only paragraph about encoding in UTF-8 but considering Windows users:

> ```
>  The use of fancy quotes (see ‘sQuote’) can cause problems when
>  setting R output.  Either set ‘options(useFancyQuotes = FALSE)’ or
>  arrange that LaTeX is aware of the encoding used (by a
>  ‘\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}’ declaration: Windows users of
>  ‘Sweave’ from ‘Rgui.exe’ will need to replace ‘utf8’ by ‘cp1252’
>  or similar) and ensure that typewriter fonts containing
>  directional quotes are used.
> ```

Currently running ubuntu, how can I make the SweaveInput aware of the UTF-8 encoding?

Comment: `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` doesn't work for you? I've used this on Windows and Linux and it worked both times. I must wonder, though, what is your real problem with encoding (image text not using localized characters?)?

Comment: @RomanLuštrik I have master.Rnw that SweaveInputs small.Rnw, the encoding specified by master.Rnw with `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` works but not for the part `samll.Rnw`. Clear now?

Comment: Related question: [Sweave generating invalid LaTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/28710/2693).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have had the same problem when working with Russian input in Sweave.  After some experimentation I understood that you need to pass the encoding to Sweave and Stangle *before* they start processing the file.  When they read `\usepackage`, it is too late.

The following entries in my Makefile work for me

```
%.tex:  %.rnw 
    echo "Sweave ('$<', encoding='koi8-r')" | R --slave

%.R: %.rnw
    echo "Stangle ('$<', encoding='koi8-r')" | R --slave
```

You need to change koi8-r for utf8.  Also, if you do not use Makefiles, the following shell lines should work

```
echo "Sweave ('myfile.rnw', encoding='utf8')" | R --slave
echo "Stangle ('myfile.rnw', encoding='utf8')" | R --slave
```

By the way, it seems that older versions of R did not have this problem;  I started to get them starting from 2.14.10.  Before this version they've happily read the encoding from `\usepackage[...]{inputenc}`...