# Can't compile a PDF with UTF-8 in Sweave

Tags: unicode, input-encodings, sweave, cyrillic, copy-paste

I try to compile in Sweave (R Studio) a PDF which contains cyrillic characters. The PDF-file looks nice, and the cyrillic characters display correctly. But when I try to copy some text from the PDF to a clipboard I get something like this when pasting:

```
Ðàññìîòðèì ñëåäóþùóþ ïîñòàíîâêó çàä
```

How to fix it?

I use these packages:

`\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}`

I save the `.tex` file with `UTF-8` encoding. [This](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39581/sweaveinput-with-utf-8-encoding) doesn't help. I tried to weave with Sweave as well as with Knitr. I use Ubuntu 16.04 and R Studio 0.99.896.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) This question is very similar to https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/64188/5763. Please take a look at it as the information there might help you. If so, that's great, and we'll probably close this question as a duplicate just to keep the place tidy and to help people find answers quickly. If not, please edit your question here to explain why so that people can better focus their attention to help you.

Comment: @MartinSchröder Hello and thank you! And yes, the question that you've mentioned really solved my problem, thank you! You can close the question. Sorry for the duplicate, I thought it was a problem with an encoding.